# Dynamic form in java

Tags: java, forms

For a project I am required to take input on various slides that ask questions. I then need to take and decide based on each question what slides to display next so that we do not ask the user unnecessary questions. My question is what the best general practice for this if one exists. Each of my slides are contained in their own objects as they not only display information but store it. I would rather not have to do this with 10+ slides:

```
public void nextStep(){
    if(track.getCurrent() instanceof Access){

    }
    else if(track.getCurrent() instanceof BasicInformation){

    }
    else if(track.getCurrent() instanceof CustomerSelect){

    }
    else if(track.getCurrent() instanceof DocumentSelect){

    }
    else if(track.getCurrent() instanceof Export){

    }
    else if(track.getCurrent() instanceof Field){

    }
    else if(track.getCurrent() instanceof HourlyWork){

    }
    else if(track.getCurrent() instanceof Import){

    }
    else if(track.getCurrent() instanceof MoreInformation){

    }
    else if(track.getCurrent() instanceof Plumbing){

    }
    else if(track.getCurrent() instanceof Pumps){

    }
    else if(track.getCurrent() instanceof QuoteType){

    }
}
```

If a better option exists. I understand this is kind of a tricky question and am sorry in advance if I am being confusing.

Comment: Is this for a web app? - Also, read this page http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to help you formulate a better question (it's kind of vague at the moment)

Comment: Assuming BasicInformation (and all of other class types in your if) are some sort of a 'form/page'.  You could inherit them all from a super class (i.e. BaseForm) with the methods `getNext()` and `getPrevious()` and define where to go in each implementation. This will help you can decide where to go next/previous based on your current 'form/page'

Comment: @blurfus almost like the Chain of Responsibility pattern?:http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain-of-responsibility_pattern

Comment: That makes perfect sense actually, the classes are actually all inherited from a super class, and I didnt think of doing that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assumption: `BasicInformation` (and all of other class types in your `if` statement) are some sort of a 'form/page'.

You could inherit them all from a super class (i.e. `BaseForm`) with the methods `getNext()` and `getPrevious()` and define where to go in each implementation. This will help you can decide where to go next/previous based on your current 'form/page'

For example:

```
public BasicInformation extends BaseForm{
    private BaseForm next;
    private BaseForm previous;

    // setters for the above
    // ...

    public BaseForm getNext(){
        return next;
    }

    public BaseForm getPrevious(){
        return previous;
    }
}
```

Then in your program you could

```
public void nextStep(BaseForm track){
    BaseForm nextStep = track.getNext();

    // do whatever you want with nextStep
    // ...
}
```